# What is the best method to correct a BuildContext error?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

```
MAIN.DART

import 'package:brew_crew/screens/wrapper.dart';
import 'package:brew_crew/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:brew_crew/models/user.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //wrapping material app with StreamProvider widget
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

AUTHENTICATE.DART

import 'package:brew_crew/screens/authenticate/sign_in.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Authenticate extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthenticateState createState() => _AuthenticateState();
}

class _AuthenticateState extends State<Authenticate> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: SignIn(),
    );
  }
}

HOME.DART
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text('home'),
    );
  }
}

WRAPPER.DART
import 'package:brew_crew/screens/authenticate/authenticate.dart';
import 'package:brew_crew/screens/home/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:brew_crew/models/user.dart';

class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    //print(user);

    // this to return either Home or Authenticate widget
    if (user == null) {
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
      return Home();
    }
  }
}

AUTH.DART

import 'package:brew_crew/models/user.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthService {
// creating an instance to help us communicate with firebase backend

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

// creating a new function to create a user object based on FirebaseUser
  User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

//auth change user stream
  Stream<User> get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }

//create a method to sign in anon
  Future signInAnon() async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);

      //just incase there is error when this is called, we can figure it out with this
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

SIGN_IN.DART

import 'package:brew_crew/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  //this is to define an instance for the sign in auth service
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.brown[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[400],
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: Text('Sign In to Brew Crew'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 50.0),
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Sign in Anon'),
          //when called, this will return either user(if successful) or null
          onPressed: () async {
            dynamic result = await _auth.signInAnon();
            if (result == null) {
              print('error signing in');
            } else {
              print('signed in');
              print(result.uid);
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error below keeps popping up when I try to run these codes. I have tried to restart and this time, it didn't build (rather this error message was seen:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.)

How can I fix this?

The project is a User sign-in form using Flutter and Firebase

THE ERROR MESSAGE

C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/delegate_widget.dart:194:18: Error: Superclass has no method named 'inheritFromElement'.
return super.inheritFromElement(ancestor, aspect: aspect);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/provider.dart:259:19: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.

- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
  ? context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(type) as InheritedProvider
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/provider.dart:260:19: Error: The method 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType'.
  : context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(type)?.widget

Comment: Looks like you are using provider. Have you wrapped your material widget?

Comment: Yes, I have, on MAIN.DART, I wrapped it with the StreamProvider widget